# How to properly create MariaDB database in another folder?

Tags: mysql, permissions, debian

I'm trying to create database in another folder instead of default /var/lib/mysql. Firstly, I created a database using `CREATE DATABASE db2;`, moved it to /home, created a symlink with `ln -s /home/mysql/db2`, then restarted my server.

The problem: MariaDB doesn't see newly created database after restart. When I'm trying to create it again, I'm getting `ERROR 13 (HY000): Can't get stat of './db2' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")`

OS: Debian 11
Server version: 10.6.9-MariaDB MariaDB Server

````
File: /home/mysql/db2
Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 208142338   Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (  107/   mysql)   Gid: (  113/   mysql)```
````

Comment: Also tried chmod 1777, doesn't help. Disabling AppArmor = no result too.

Comment: If i'm trying to use data directory while creating table i'm getting ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `db2`.`website` (errno: 168 "Unknown (generic) error from engine")

Answer (score 0):

Not a fix but a workaround.

Consider using MySQL Community Edition (>8.0) especially on Debian 11. SAME configuration = everything works.